# How to access Ruby configuration variables from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I added a configuration variable in application.rb such as

```
module Www
    class Application < Rails::Application
      ...
      config.myurl = "http://localhost:8443/play"
end
```

After something is clicked on my page I would like to use the value of this config var in order to come up with my full url such as mypage.js having

```
function ClickedOnSomething(someid){
    var fullUrl = <value of config.myurl> + '?id='+someid+'.html'; 
    ...
}
```

so that if for example the id of what I clicked on was 1776 then the fullUrl would be the string 
`http://localhost:8443/play?id=1776.html`

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3

One thing I tried was going through the controller like the following:

In application_controller.rb I added

```
def before_filter
  # This variable will be available in all controller actions and views
  @url_global = Www::Application.config.myurl
end
```

In application.html.erb I added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url_global = "<%= @url_global %>"
</script>
```

Then in mypage.js I did

```
function ClickedOnSomething(someid){
    var fullUrl = @url_global + '?id='+someid+'.html'; 
    ...
}
```

but @url_global is not recognized. I have actually tried many different variations of using the var in javascript but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you declare

```
var url_global = "<%= @url_global %>";
```

so you have to use url_global in function, not @url_global;

```
var fullUrl = url_global + '?id='+someid+'.html';
```

Am I correct?

Comment: I did try it that way without the @ and the variable wasn't being recognized either.

Comment: Can you open the rendered page by using view source in your browser? Send me the code it rendered

Comment: changing it to url_global without the @ did work after all.
I just realized my problem was that in application_controller.rb I had before_filter twice. So I had 

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_cache_buster

and then later on I had

def before_filter
  # This variable will be available in all controller actions and views
  @url_global = Www::Application.config.myurl
end

So my guess is that the def was being skipped altogether

However, I am curious if there is a better way to access config variables in javascript